# Functions and Procedures Giving type Conversion Error with SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I recently migrated my DB from Sql Server 2008 to SQL 2016.
When I tried connecting the DB to my application using SQL Login Functions and Procedures are giving type conversion Error with SQL Server 2016.

(The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.)

However, when executing them with windows login they are working fine.

This is happening with almost all functions and procedures.

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any debugging to find where the error is coming from? Can you post the code causing the issue?

Comment: Everything is working fine with windows login in SSMS.
But things break when I do SQL login in the same DB for the same Stored procedures and functions.

So I am of opinion that  it may not be an issue with SPs and Functions, since they are working with windows login in the same DB on the same Server.

Comment: Yeah so there must be some code throwing that error - where is the error occurring? Can you post the code that is throwing the error?

Comment: Error Code

"Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: So when is that error occurring? Is it when you run a procedure? Is it all procedures? We need more information to help you.

Comment: > [You can refer this question for your help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506611/type-date-is-not-a-defined-system-type)

Comment: @Ankit Bhalala -> That is for SQL Server version < 2005 , but I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: @AnuragRaj,did you checked https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116590/the-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link for solve your problem

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-242.aspx

Comment: The Solution given by Md Haider Ali khan helped .

Thanks for the support and instant help!!